# File data read to map, but map::find() doesn't work

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to find a key/value pair in a map, but due to how the map is populated, for some reason `map::find()` doesn't work.

The data it reads from can be boiled down to

```
Key1,a,b,c
Key2,a
Key3
Key4,a,b
```

With this I could print out all this data using an iterator loop, but `map::find()` does not work with `Key3` or `Key4`.

Data is gathered from the file as such:

```
file.open("input.txt");
std::string line;
std::string key;
while(getline(file,line,','))
{
    key = line;
    getline(file,line);
    m[key]=line;
}
```

Which can be printed with:

```
for(auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout<<it->first<<","<<it->second<<std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Key1,a,b,c
Key2,a
Key3
Key4,a,b
```

But for whatever reason, `Key3` and `Key4` don't exist according to `map::find()`.

I've tried checking error bits, manually setting the value for `Key3`, nothing seems to work that allows me to use `map::find()` for values after `Key3`. (map::find() returns map.end() for those values)

I'm almost certain it's because of how I gather the data, specifically because `Key3` doesn't have a comma, but I have to leave it in that form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while(getline(file,line,','))

The line above is looking for a delimiter ','.
However, since line 3 in your file does not have a ',' it effectively reads [Key3\nKey4] as the key.

Hence the error.

Since you cannot change the file, I would suggest read the entire line with the default delimiter '\n' and then parse from the populated string.

Just to note, however, you will need a sentinel value for Key3 if you want it to exist in the map, or use the map::count() member function to check for existence.

Comment: I don't think this is the case.  I agree that the delimiter is probably the issue, but I don't think that the print statement would work if this were the case.  Attempting to find [Key3\nKey4] also yields no results.

Comment: What is the answer for this print statement?  cout << m["Key3\nKey4"] << endl ? .

Comment: While I didn't try this, I did try map::find("Key3\nKey4"), and that yielded map.end().  However, I have posted a solution based on your original suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: @Caleb The print is misleading. You're looking at four lines of output and mentally equating that with four loop iterations, but that ignores the consequence of writing a `'\n'` to standard output within a string. It would be clear if you surrounded each iteration's output with like a `std::cout << "ITERATION #" << i << '\n';` or something

Comment: I can understand that it could be printing this in such a way, but wouldn't `m["Key3\nKey4"]` give a value other than `map::end` if this were the case?  This is purely hypothetical at this point, as the the problem as already been solved.

Answer (score 0):

So while this doesn't explain what the original issue was, here is the solution I found.

Gathering data from the file is now

```
file.open("input.txt");
std::string line;
std::string key;
std::stringstream ss;
while(getline(file,line,'\n'))
{
    ss << line;
    getline(ss,line,',');
    key = line;
    getline(ss,line,'\n');
    m[key] = line;
    ss.clear();
}
```

Getting data from the file this way guarantees that the data is read correctly now, courtesy of user3389943

Comment: This solution is literally what user3389943 gave you, and the explanation is found in the same answer.